# Cabal: cabal configure fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

This question is only [yak-shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving) to try and troubleshoot [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986854/haskell-ghc-using-haddock-on-osx).

So, in an attempt to diagnose another problem of mine, I was advised to try:

```
cabal unpack base
cd base-4.3.1.0
cabal haddock
```

To see what that did.

Only, when I did `cabal unpack base`, it unpacked `base-3.0.3.2`.  Then `cabal haddock` complained that I needed to run `cabal configure` first then that failed (lost the exact error, sadly).

So I decided to install base-4.3.1.0, just so I could reenact the instructions exactly.
Even after install, `cabal unpack base` unpacks `base-3.0.3.2`, though `cabal unpack base-4.3.1.0` unpacks `base-4.3.1.0`.

Now I'm can't get either to configure:

```
% cabal unpack base
Unpacking to base-3.0.3.2/
% cd base-3.0.3.2
% cabal haddock
cabal: Run the 'configure' command first.
% cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring base-3.0.3.2...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base >=4.0 && <4.3, syb ==0.1.*
% cd ..
%
% cabal unpack base-4.3.1.0
Unpacking to base-4.3.1.0/
% cd base-4.3.1.0
% cabal haddock
cabal: Run the 'configure' command first.
% cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring base-4.3.1.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
...
checking for library containing iconv... -liconv
checking for library containing locale_charset... none required
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `base.buildinfo.in'
% cd ..
```

Also, I can't revert to base-3.0.3.2, because it depends on having
base version >=4.0 <4.3 (WTF?), and I can't install base-4.2.0.2 b/c it fails 
b/c it can't find `base.buildinfo.in`.

```
% cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
% cabal info base
* base             (library)
    Synopsis:      Basic libraries (backwards-compatibility version)
    Versions available: 3.0.3.1, 3.0.3.2, (4.0.0.0), (4.1.0.0), (4.2.0.0),
                        (4.2.0.1), (4.2.0.2), (4.3.0.0), (4.3.1.0)
    Versions installed: (4.3.1.0)
    Homepage:      [ Not specified ]
    Bug reports:   http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket?component=libraries/base
    Description:   This is a backwards-compatible version of the base package.
                   It depends on a later version of base, and was probably
                   supplied with your compiler when it was installed.
    License:       BSD3
    Maintainer:    libraries@haskell.org
    Source repo:   http://darcs.haskell.org/packages/base3-compat
    Dependencies:  base >=4.0 && <4.3, syb ==0.1.*
    Documentation: /usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0
    Cached:        Yes
    Modules:
    ...
%
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody is meant to self-compile `base`.  It's tied to a particular ghc installation, so you couldn't use any other base package if you built it.  I'm not surprised that the base package doesn't build from hackage; most likely nobody ever tries to build it.

Anyway, I'd try [checking out the ghc source](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/GettingTheSources).  The `base.buildinfo.in` file will be in the [base package repo](http://darcs.haskell.org/packages/base/).  You could copy the file from the repo to your unpacked distribution, but it's probably better to just build from the checked-out source.

Just be sure to only install the docs and not the library.